# How do I merge wallet data from multiple wallets that control the same address?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-data, light-wallet, feature-request

Consider a scenario with the following facts:

- I have a Monero node at my home.  It contains a wallet, but I generally don't use that wallet.
- I have a desktop computer where I have a wallet that I restored from the same seed as the wallet on my node. Sometimes I initiate transfers from this wallet.
- I have a laptop computer where I have a wallet that I also restored from the same seed as the wallet on my node. Sometimes I initiate transfers from this wallet.

The issue is this: if I `transfer` from the desktop's wallet, only the desktop wallet will have the destination address (among other things). I want all three wallets to be able to contain the same data, even if that means I need to do some periodic copying/pasting/exporting/importing/etc.

How do I merge the transaction data in the different wallet files, so each of the wallets contain all the data from the other wallets?

Note that I have named the wallet identically in each location, if that matters.

Comment: surely the data we'd need is in file: walletname.bin and just needs to be decrypted and updated/copied to/from ? Can nobody on here guide us on how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no tooling to do this at this time.